# Best way to load a grouped collection on Xamarin.Forms ListView/CollectionView with incremental loading

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview, xamarin.forms.collectionview

What would be the best way to load a grouped collection on Xamarin.Forms ListView/CollectionView with incremental loading?

For example, say a collection contains several groups and each group contains a list of items.

```
[
    [123, 143, 341234, 234234, 514232, 23511, 673456, ...],
    [12, 143, 341234, 234234, 514232, 23511, , ...],
    [12, 143, 341234, 234234, 514232, 23511, 313, ...],
    [12, 143, 341234, 514232, 23511, 673456, ...],
    [12, 143, 341234, 234234, 514232, 132, 23511, 673456, ...],
    .
    .
    .
    [12, 143, 341234, 234234, 514232, 23511, 673456, ...],
]
```

**Update**

With one dimensional list, I could load the data into the ListView or CollectionView using `ListView.ItemAppearing`/`CollectionView.RemainingItemsThresholdReached` events.

[Infinite Scroll with Xamarin.Forms CollectionView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZq8K_64bc0)

[Load More Items at End of ListView in Xamarin.Forms](https://montemagno.com/load-more-items-at-end-of-listview-in/)

```
listView.ItemAppearing += ListView_ItemAppearing;
IList<Item> originalList = new List<Item> {Item1, ..., Item10000};

private void ListView_ItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
{
    if (// all the items in the original list loaded into the listview) 
    {
        listView.ItemAppearing -= ListView_ItemAppearing;
    }
    else
    {
        // Add next set of items from the original list to the listview
    }
}
```

So my concern is, what would be the best way (or the best practice) to load incrementally **a grouped collection** into a `ListView` or `CollectionView`?

Comment: Please refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58366576/how-can-i-creat-endless-scrolling-in-xamarin
This will answer your question.

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT I don't want to scroll the list infinitely. Sorry for the misinterpretation, I have updated the question.

Comment: You can set a list(A) contains lists of the object you want to display. And add new list  into the list(A) in the ListView.ItemAppearing/CollectionView.RemainingItemsThresholdReached events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load grouped collection, I add some plus data into the ItemsSource like:

```
    PersonViewModel pvm = new PersonViewModel();
           private  ObservableCollection<PersonGroup> myitems = new ObservableCollection<PersonGroup>();
            public TestGroup()
            {
    
                InitializeComponent();
                myitems = pvm.Persons;
                //set collectionview
                mycol.ItemsSource =myitems;
                mycol.RemainingItemsThreshold = 2;
                mycol.RemainingItemsThresholdReached += Mycol_RemainingItemsThresholdReached;
            }
    
            private void Mycol_RemainingItemsThresholdReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               
                for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
                {
                    myitems.Add(new PersonGroup("plusgroup", new List<Person> { new 
                    Person { name="plus1",
                    address="11111"},
                   new Person { name="plus2",
                    address="22222"}
    
                     }));
                }
            }
```

Here are my viewmodel and model:

```
public class PersonViewModel {


    public ObservableCollection<PersonGroup> Persons { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<PersonGroup>();

    public List<Person> peoplelist = new List<Person>();

    public PersonViewModel()

    {

        for (int k = 1; k <= 3; k++)

        {

           peoplelist.Add(new Person
            {
                name = "People" + k.ToString(),

                address = "somewhere"+k.ToString()
            });

        }


        for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++)

        {

            Persons.Add(new PersonGroup("Group" + i.ToString(), peoplelist));

        }

    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class PersonGroup{
    public string GroupName { set; get; }
    
            public  PersonGroup(string name,List<Person>persons):base(persons)
            {
                GroupName = name;
            }
    
        }
```

result:

[image]